# extract two different date string between one special characters

Tags: php, html

I have some problem.

I have some data from my post on date range picker
there are

"10/04/2013 - 10/26/2013"

I want to get

date1 = "10/04/2013"

and
date2 = "10/26/2013"

for my between date query..
please help me
Thank you for your attention

Comment: if the data are getted from a form... well... you can use the "splice" to obtain two strings, then trimming it and then you will have two vars with the data how you want.

Comment: I tried with pregmatch and have no idea, im sorry, im very noob on Text Processing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/explode)

```
$string="10/04/2013 - 10/26/2013"; //Your string
$exploded = explode('-', $string); //Explode using -

echo $exploded[0]; //echo string 1
echo $exploded[1]; //echo string 2
```

Note: You will have to use [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/trim) if you want to get rid of the white space, else in the `explode()` first parameter, use the spaces before and after the `-` like `explode(' - ', $string)`

Comment: `echo $exploded[0];` or `echo $string[0];`?

Comment: Its work!, but little correction
change : $string[0] with $exploded[0]

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw thanks for pointing it out, was just a typo :) -harris you welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

For mysql query the date format should be as "YYYY-mm-dd"

Your input comes as MM/dd/YYYY

You may need to convert that to mysql format before firing the query

In that case you can use strtotime()

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime("10/04/2013"));
```

will give you 2013-10-04